# Equivalent of every-pred, but for any of the given predicates

Tags: clojure

Any cuter way to express this?

```
#(or (:a %) (b: %) (:c %)) ;; would prefer (desired-fn :a :b :c)
```

clojure.core lacks a "any-pred" function, maybe because there is already a means of providing the same functionality? Or would have one to implement it himself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`some-fn`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some-fn) is what you're looking for. The only difference is that `some-fn` will return `false` rather than `nil` in the case where none of the functions return a logically true value.

Just as a note on naming: it's not called "some-pred"/"any-pred" because predicates only return `true` or `false`, whereas `some-fn` will return the first logically true value (which may not be `true` itself).