# Compose multiple predicate functions into one

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, composition

Is it possible to compose for example:

```clj
(defn- multiple-of-three? [n] (zero? (mod n 3))
(defn- multiple-of-five? [n] (zero? (mod n 5))
```

into:

```clj
multiple-of-three-or-five?
```

so I can use it for filtering:

```clj
(defn sum-of-multiples [n]
  (->> (range 1 n)
       (filter multiple-of-three-or-five?)
       (reduce +)))
```

Also I don't want to define it like this:

```clj
(defn- multiple-of-three-or-five? [n]
  (or (multiple-of-three? n)
      (multiple-of-five? n)))
```

For example with Javascript module Ramda it would be achieved as: http://ramdajs.com/docs/#either

```js
const multipleOfThreeOrFive = R.either(multipleOfThree, multipleOfFive)
```

Comment: You need to do the `or` and you can combine the expressions from your two existing into one in the new `multiple-of-three-or-five?`= `(or (zero? (mod n 3)) (zero? (mod n 5)))` which will eliminate another 1-2 function calls.

Comment: Yeah, but imagine 2 much more complex predicate functions with different meaning. It would be better to keep them separated. I just want to understand how it could be achieved in clojure (even with library if exists).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17259965

Comment: Good ol' fizzbuzz eh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, in Clojure this is [`some-fn`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some-fn).

```
(def multiple-of-three-or-five?
  (some-fn multiple-of-three? multiple-of-five?))
```

```
(multiple-of-three-or-five? 3)  ; => true
(multiple-of-three-or-five? 4)  ; => false
(multiple-of-three-or-five? 5)  ; => true
```

Comment: Great, that's what I needed.