# Is there a threaded way to perform an "or" (or any test) condition in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Something along the lines of:

```clj
(or->
    "foobar"
    (clojure.string/starts-with? "foo")
    (clojure.string/starts-with? "bar"))

=> true
```

If not, what is the idiomatic way to perform a test with multiple ors/ands?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/45643579.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you need only tests or some threading feature too. Have a look at cond-> and cond->>.

Answer (score 10):

I'd use [`some`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some) here. It's essentially a sequence friendly `or` check that can help cut down on duplication when all the conditions are basically the same:

```
(some #(clojure.string/starts-with? "foobar" %)
      ["foo" "bar"])
```

It uses an early return.

---

The `and` equivalent of `some` would be `every?`:

```
(every? odd? [3 5 9])
=> true
```

Answer (score 3):

We need to insert the first argument into all the successive clauses before they are evaluated. So the solution must be a macro. If we're prepared to do without syntax checking, we can define it quite concisely:

```
(defmacro or-> [arg & pred-exprs]
  (let [insert-expr (fn [[x & xs]] (list* x arg xs))
        inserted-exprs (map insert-expr pred-exprs)]
    (cons 'or inserted-exprs)))
```

It works:

```
problem=> (or-> "foobar" 
                (clojure.string/starts-with? "foo")
                (clojure.string/starts-with? "bar"))
true

problem=> (or-> "foobar"
                (clojure.string/starts-with? "for")
                (clojure.string/starts-with? "bar"))
false
```

But it evaluates the `arg` form for every clause attempted. To evaluate the `arg` form just once, we insert a `let` form for a `gensym`:

```
(defmacro or-> [arg & pred-exprs]
  (let [arg-sym (gensym)
        insert-arg (fn [[x & xs]] (list* x arg-sym xs))
        inserted-exprs (map insert-arg pred-exprs)]
    `(let [~arg-sym ~arg] (or ~@inserted-exprs))))
```

I'd like to have done this with auto-gensym, but I can's figure out how. However it's done, this is not threading in the normal Clojure sense, which always performs all the threaded clauses.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, you really need to use `or` and a symbol:

```
(defn check [val]
  (or
    (= val "foobar")
    (clojure.string/starts-with? val "foo")
    (clojure.string/starts-with? val "bar")))

(check "foobar") => true
(check "foosball") => true
(check "barbell") => true
(check "egg-foo-yung") => false
```